# Iterate through JSON and pass it to tokeninput

Tags: jquery, json

Let's say I've JSON in the following format

```
`[{"id":1,"name":"aaa"},
 {"id":2,"name":"bbb"},
 {"id":3,"name":"ccc"}]`
```

Using the above JSON, i've to extract each row from it and pass it to tokeninput Jquery plugin in the format below:

```
$("#to").tokenInput("add", {"id":1,"name":"aaa"})
$("#to").tokenInput("add", {"id":2,"name":"bbb"})
$("#to").tokenInput("add", {"id":3,"name":"ccc"})
```

how can i do this using Jquery?

Comment: downvote and three answers, heh! Not bad :)

Comment: I was trying this way, var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(res);
                $.each(obj, function(key, value) {                    
                    $("#to").tokenInput("add", obj);
                });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $.each(data, function (index, element) {

                           $("#to").tokenInput("add", {"id":element.id,"name":element.name})

                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Below should work

```
 var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

    $.each(obj, function(ob){
       $("#to").tokenInput("add",ob);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery each() function. For your example,

```
var names = [{"id":1,"name":"aaa"},
{"id":2,"name":"bbb"},
{"id":3,"name":"ccc"}];

$.each(names, function(index, value) {
    $("#to").tokenInput("add", value);
});
```